# https link insecure

Tags: force.com-sites

I have a `Visualforce Page` hosted on a `Site`.

For one of the user, the `https:` portion of the url is stricken through with a red line stating the page is not secure.

[image: Insecure https]

But for rest of the users, the page is secure.

[image: Secure https]

What might be the possible reason? Where to start?

Comment: Are you sure they are using the secure url and not the standard. should contain `secure.force.com` unless you have custom domains...

Comment: I can see both URL are different. First one is without www and second one is without www. Are you using custom domain?